# Navigation menu items with dropdown menu Android

Tags: android, xml

I'm using Navigation Drawer. I've used a spinner layout in a menu item, but it looks bad. I'm trying to have a view like this, but IDK how.
[image: Text]

So when I press PRODUCT, a dropdown submenu appears.

I've tried this code to do so but it's not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_home_24"
            android:title="@string/home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_products"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:visible="true"
         android:actionLayout="@android:layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_shopping_bag_24"
            app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
            android:title="@string/products" >
            <menu>
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/fire_alam"
                        android:title="@string/fire_alarms"
                        android:checkable="true"
                        app:showAsAction="never"
                        />
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/fire_fighting"
                        android:checkable="true"
                        app:showAsAction="never"
                        android:title="@string/fire_fighting"/>
            </menu>
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_serv"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_room_service_24"
            android:title="@string/services" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ExpandableListView`

**Check:-** https://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial

Also you can use it in `NavigationView`

**Check:-**
https://www.journaldev.com/19375/android-expandablelistview-navigationview